# How to get only the value back from Postgres without the table name and id?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The below line gets the value into the 'dataFrame' together with the 'table name' so when I try to use it I get the error: InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'club_url\n0 ...
Thanks for looking.

```
dataFrame = pds.read_sql("SELECT club_url FROM premier_league WHERE club_name LIKE '%%Chel%%'", dbConnection)
```

Full list of error messages:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File

```
"C:\Users\zszen\PycharmProjects\venv\Football\Scripts\import_players_csv.py", line 23, in <module>
    r = s.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\zszen\PycharmProjects\venv\Football\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zszen\PycharmProjects\venv\Football\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zszen\PycharmProjects\venv\Football\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 695, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\zszen\PycharmProjects\venv\Football\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 792, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'club_url\n0  https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/fc-chelsea/sta...'
                                            club_url
0  https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/fc-chelsea/sta...
```

Comment: Define/show "try to use it". Also show the complete error message. Add as update to question.

Comment: The traceback is completely unrelated to `read_sql`.  Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What is the code that is creating the error?

Comment: - The code creating the error is the line provided dataFrame = pds.read_sql("SELECT club_url FROM premier_league WHERE club_name LIKE '%%Chel%%'", dbConnection). I'd like a way to show the value only not as you can see at the bottom> table name: club_url returned, and also the position of the value is returned '0'. and the value itself is the 'url'.

Comment: Traceback shows requests has an issue, but it has the issue because I am feeding requests the wrong url. The database stores the value I want to use, but the way read_sql works it also loads the <table name> and position. If it only returned my valid url there would be no error. The traceback is not related to read_sql but my question is. I can't produce an example because you do not have my database. Would this help:  from requests_html import HTMLSession    
s = HTMLSession() url = dataFrame     r = s.get(url)    print(r)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.values` at the end of the line that will get you the values or value as a list.